# Draw outline for the pie chart

Tags: android, graph, achartengine, pie-chart

i am using a chart engine to draw graph it works fine but i need to add an outline to the pie chart? how to do that

i have checked this

[Link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/achartengine/iuJIUXxNsLY)

and the graph should be something like this

[graph image](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/713/techpiechart.gif/)

Comment: Dan i have one more query please see this, and yes its correct i will accept it now so that it will help others.

Comment: Dan See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14499523/achart-engine-onclick-pie-chart-slice-not-working-sometimes-a-bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not yet supported. You can create an issue in the AChartEngine tracker and ask for this to be implemented.