# Achart engine Onclick pie chart slice not working sometimes a bug?

Tags: android, achartengine, pie-chart

i am working on a pie chart and i am using AchartEngine.

i have the pie chart like this:

[Image of a Pie Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qF7JG.png)

i have added the onclick to the slices but sometimes only the green slice onlick will not work.

this is my code:

```
mChartView = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(this, adc.buildCategoryDataset("Project budget", values), renderer);
        mChartView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChartView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
              if (seriesSelection == null) {
                  Toast
                      .makeText(GeneratedChartDemo.this, "No chart element was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                      .show();
                } else {
                  Toast.makeText(
                          GeneratedChartDemo.this,
                      "Chart element data point index " + seriesSelection.getPointIndex()
                          + " was clicked" + " point value=" + seriesSelection.getValue(),
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
          });
```

where am i going wrong have i missed something?

**EDIT**

Thanks to Dan who helped me in solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add a selectable buffer?

```
mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
mRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(10);
```

Update: there was a bug that I fixed. You can download a version including this fix [here](https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.1.0/).

Comment: what the values are there in the piechart just add it and check at this point green slice is not clickable

Comment: There is a bug indeed. I will try to fix it and will let you know.

Comment: Dan please try to make it as soon as possible i have to submit, this is my sincere request

Comment: yes i will accept as it also help others,approx how much time will it take is it a major or minor?

Comment: ok please let me know once it done as i am also trying to fix that as i have already edited the source code

Comment: Take a look at my latest checkin into SVN. I will build a jar as well.

Comment: can you please share the link

Comment: please tell me in which class have you made the changes as i have edited the source code

Comment: only changed in this isInSegment() ? nothing else?

Comment: I cannot maintain your modified source code. Use the version I am publishing. What means "not working"? Is there a stack trace?

Comment: No still the same its not clickable and i have made the currentAngle = -45;is it because of that?

Comment: Just make the current angle whatever positive value.

Comment: renderer.setStartAngle(45);

Comment: ok thanks will check that and please dont mind if i am disturbing you

Comment: Dan i checked it if we try to give the renderer.setStartAngle(45);  and with values 2 for green, 12 for blue and 5 for red again red slice is not clickable at some point

Comment: I have just checked and it is working for me. Just use the release version I mentioned above, not some locally modified thing.

Comment: The comments are not a good place for long discussions, please move to the chat if you want to continue!

Comment: @Dan just check this once http://i.imgur.com/rQLsQPO.png click on the white box and check with the same values which i have given and i am using the latest revision code

Comment: have you added renderer.setStartAngle(45); and checked, i am still having the same bug. it work fine for 0.0

Comment: Just use the achartengine.jar I mentioned, not your locally hacked thing. I have tested using the values you mentioned.

Comment: ok yes i am using the same file you have made changes only in isInSegment() method in PieSegment class if i am correct? or have you made any other changes ?

Comment: Check again. I made one more change.

Comment: @Dan yes cheers it works fine now thanks a ton only one small thing if we can make that start angle to -45 or please help on that logic rest i will do it by myself

Comment: Just make it 315 and let me breath now.

Comment: ok i made all the 360 to 315 now on click of green slice returns us red slice value and i am really sorry for disturbing you again and again

Comment: Do renderer.setStartAngle(315); Don't hack the AChartEngine code! I stop now answering your questions!